# Most Up-To-Date C# Duck-Typing Library

Tags: c#, duck-typing

What is the current state of the art on duck typing for C# below version 4.0?

I know about [Duck Typing Project](http://www.deftflux.net/blog/page/Duck-Typing-Project.aspx), I know that [BLTookit](http://bltoolkit.net/) has something to that end, but I'd like to know if I'm missing something really wicked apart from DLR languages and C# 4.0.

Comment: I don't see how you can do that with a library. Before the new things added in 4.0 -- C# is statically typed. Period. The additions to allow duck typing go a lot deeper than a simple library.

Comment: @Billy See my edits. This is perfectly doable in C# prior to 4.0

Comment: I'm trying to make my "DeformedDuck" "Quack()" because at the moment he only "MakeNoise()" and I've written a Quack() extension method, however the only library I've found is the one you mention, and it does not seem to support extension methods.

Answer (score 3):

Use iron python inside the c# code. We've used it very successfully.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [DLR](http://dlr.codeplex.com/Wikipage) for dynamic type capabilities pre .NET 4, though you can't use the dynamic keyword so it can be a pain. The remaining "Duck Typing" functionality looks like it can be had through something like [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

Clay, that is used in Orchard
http://clay.codeplex.com/
And here is an example and description
http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/08/18/clay-malleable-c-dynamic-objects-part-2.aspx